# Excel - Extract string between two strings

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, find

I have a vector of strings of the following kind:

```
{'id': '123', 'text': 'What should I buy today?', 'choices':[{'value': 'Bread', 'label': 'You need to buy bread', 'selected': True}, {'value': 'Milk', 'label': 'You need to buy milk', 'selected': False}, {'value': 'Chips', 'label': "You need to buy chips", 'selected': False}]}
```

I would like to create a column made of only the sentences which end with

```
'selected': True
```

For example, regarding the above string I would get

```
You need to buy bread
```

As of now, I could only write the following command:

```
=MID(LEFT(A1,FIND(", 'selected': True",G5)-1),FIND("label':",G5)+7,LEN(G5))
```

But, in case the action selected (`'selected': True`) is not the first one of the list, it won't work.

---

New added:

[image]

Comment: Then find selected and trap that text and then test for true etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another formula option and without LET function for all Excel versions.

The criteria ('selected': True) can be put in the 1st, 2nd or last position of the list as per following example.

In `C2`, formula copied down :

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"""","'"),FIND(", 'selected': True",A2)-2),"'",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly even with my Excel version!

Answer (score 2):

With Office 365, you can do:

```
=LET( line, D3,
       sentences, MID( line, FIND( "[", line ), 99999),
       sarr, FILTERXML( "<m><s>" & SUBSTITUTE( sentences, "{", "</s><s>" ) & "</s></m>", "//s" ),
       larr, INDEX( sarr, FILTER( SEQUENCE( ROWS( sarr ) ), ISNUMBER( FIND( "'selected': True", sarr ) ) ) ),
       s, FIND( "'label': '", larr)+10, f, FIND( "',", larr, s ),
       MID( larr, s, f-s )  )
```

Where D3 is your target cell with your original line.

I suspect there is an easier way with a better FILTERXML hack, but it does not come to me at the moment. If JvdV is on line, he would know. Also, P.b. would probably do this in a better way.

> NB: you must be consistent with string definitions. You must use ' as
> opposed to ".

[image]

Another approach is to force the conversions of " to '.  This will do that, but it may have unintended consequences:

```
=LET( line, D3,
       sentences, MID( SUBSTITUTE( line,"""","'"), FIND( "[", line ), 99999),
       sarr, FILTERXML( "<m><s>" & SUBSTITUTE( sentences, "{", "</s><s>" ) & "</s></m>", "//s" ),
       larr, INDEX( sarr, FILTER( SEQUENCE( ROWS( sarr ) ), ISNUMBER( FIND( "'selected': True", sarr ) ) ) ),
       s, FIND( "'label': '", larr)+10, f, FIND( "',", larr, s ),
       MID( larr, s, f-s )  )
```

Comment: If you don't have Office365, then VBA might be the way to go about it (you can reverse the string to search for the last occurrence, or even parse JSON)

Comment: That was not so straightforward and it took me a while but my two cents: `=LET(A,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3),"}, {","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[substring(., string-length(.)-3)='True']"),B,MID(A,FIND("'label'",A)+10,LEN(A)),LEFT(B,FIND("'selected'",B)-4))`

Comment: @JvdV - always magic!

Comment: Thank you so much @JvdV I have pasted my result with your method but I keep finding an error.

Comment: @Mary, the `#NAME` error suggests that either you don't have MS365 (thus access to `LET()` and dynamic spilled arrays) or you'r working with Excel for Mac (thus don't have access to `FILTERXML()`). What version of Excel are you working with?

Comment: @JvdV It is Microsoft Excel 2019 MSO (16.0.10382.20010) 64-BIT, I am not using a Mac

Comment: Then it's still possible without `LET()` but a complete nightmare with nested functions of `FILTERXML()`. Rather go with PowerQuery and pass your input as JSON. @Mary